# Comparing models with partially observed data and limited supervision

Tags: accuracy, model-comparison

**Setup**: Suppose we have $n$ questions and for each question $m$ answers. For each question, a model, **Model A**, selects one answer out of $m$. Note that for each question, zero, one, or more answers could be correct, but the model only selects exact one to answer the question. At the end, an oracle judges if each question is correctly answered. Based on this we can compute the accuracy of Model A. For example, if 50 of 100 questions are correctly answered, the accuracy of Model A is 50%. (This accuracy corresponds to Model A's capability to select a good answer.)

**Question**: Now suppose we have a new model, **Model B**. Can we tell if Model B is better than Model A *without* calling the oracle again? Putting differently, can we judge Model B's performance based on the data we had with Model A?